# Web API code compiles but doesn't run in one specific machine on both Visual Studio and VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

So I am modifying an WEB Api wrote in C# using .NET 3.1
The code compiles without any errors, the API is able to listen to requests but is not able to send any response.
The problem is: It only occurs in my machine, my colleague tried it out and it works as expected.
Since then I tried:
Reinstall nuget dependencies
Reinstall and update Visual Studio 2019
Reinstall .NET 3.1 and . NET 4
Cleaned and rebuild the code multiple times

Because it happens in both VS Code and Visual Studio I am guessing it’s something related to my system and not the IDE. Anyone experienced a similar issue and is able to give some advice?

I am running Windows 10 v1909

Comment: Hi, what I would recommend is that you write a very simple webapi, for example a "Hello, World!" type of application and see if that works for you. If that works, then you know it isn't an issue with your system. You could slowly add your original code to the tutorial code and keep testing until it breaks. You can then analyze why it broke. Good luck.

Comment: Tried and the other api runs without a problem. Seems to be something related to this machine and my application. Anyway tks for the advice